# Otto does not call to @Subscribe

Tags: android, otto

I am working in a Hello Otto basic project in order to learn a bit how it works. This is my BusProvider over Otto 7.0.1. In MainActivity I have two buttons, after tap on the first one I post a string in the bus object. This is my BusProvider

```
public class  BusProvider {

    private BusProvider() {}

    private static Bus bus;
    public static Bus getInstance() {
        if (bus == null){
            bus = new Bus();
        }
        return bus;
    }
}
```

MainActivity who will sent a String to Main2Activity using the bus class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Bus bus;
    @Bind(R.id.myButton)Button mButton;
    @Bind(R.id.button2)Button mButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setLibreries();
        this.bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void setLibreries(){
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.myButton)
    protected void buttonPressed1( ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "click on the 1 button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BusProvider.getInstance().post("HELLO OTTO");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button2)
    protected void buttonPressed(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "click on the 2 button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Main2Activity how receives the String

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Bus bus;

    @Bind(R.id.this_is_a_text_view) TextView myTextButter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        myTextButter.setText("HELLO");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void gettingStringPosted(String message){
        Log.d("OTTO", "OTTO subscribe has been called "+message);
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

The problem is that the Toast with the message I am sending in MainActivity to Main2Activity

> HELLO OTTO

is never showed.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try registering the bus in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes I did ,  in onResume but does not work

Comment: That's okay you are registering BusProvider in onResume method of Main2Activity. But You are posting before Main2Activity created. How could this happen ?

Comment: mmm... I  see, so when I have to post the String , after start the Main2Activity?

Comment: does not work either after startActivity(intent);

Comment: It must be registered before you post. And are you sure that onResume method has been called before you post ? So this scenario is a bit weird, if you wanna send something from Activity to another(when switching), Intent is ideal for this purpose, you can put the things in it.

Comment: Yes I know is weird, is just a test in order to know how the otto library works.... Can  you please add with code about what are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Main2Activity has not been registered yet to Otto when your `BusProvider.getInstance().post("HELLO OTTO");` line comes.

Here is how your code does:

1. Bus.post()
2. Bus.register()

This is how it should go:

1. Bus.register()
2. Bus.post()

---

You can't solve this by moving the line `BusProvider.getInstance().post("HELLO OTTO");` under the `startActivity()` call because `Activity.onResume()` might not get called straight away so your register call (in onResume) could still happen **after** post call. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes makes sense, thanks a lot , but the thing is that Main2Activity never can be register because is created after the click method? is not it? ...I have tried your solution moving to startActivity but does not work, anyway I have it more clear

Comment: Surely it can be registered after the click method, but it might not get registered SOON ENOUGH. So all I am trying to say is that don't use Otto in these kind of situations :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just example of otto, to make sense how it is. Let's assume you have a service, and in it getting locations and sending to activities.

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    Bus bus;     

    LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            bus.post(new MyLocation(location));
        }
    };

    // Other service related methods.. 

}
```

And activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void locationChanged(MyLocation location){
    Toast.makeText(this, "you got new location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Thats just it.

BTW, and this is the what i mentioned for you in my comment

In MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_INFO", "INFO");
startActivity(intent)
```

In Main2Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String info = intent.getStringExtra("MY_INFO");
}
```